Pyproject.toml setuptools_scm version_file setting not working in GitHub publish action
This is my first time using Pyproject.toml and GitHub actions and I've run into and issue my publish.yml job.
In my pyproject.toml file I have this setting
[tool.setuptools_scm]
version_file = "flashback/_version.py"
My directory structure is this for the Python project
flashback
--- _version.py
--- pyproject.toml
Looks right according to the setuptools_scm documentation (I think) yet when I run my publish.yml GitHub action file in which I set my project directory to 'project_directory: "./flaskback"' I'm getting this error--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/verify.py", line 20, in <module>
    version = semantic_version.Version(version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/semantic_version/base.py", line 105, in __init__
    major, minor, patch, prerelease, build = self.parse(version_string, partial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/semantic_version/base.py", line 309, in parse
    raise ValueError('Invalid empty version string: %r' % version_string)
ValueError: Invalid empty version string: ''

Any and all help is appreciated
Bill
